# Changing fill-column of elisp docstrings

Tags: fill-paragraph, emacs-lisp-mode

When I'm writing the docstring for a `defun` or a `defvar`, if hit
`M-q` the paragraph always gets filled to 65 characters, regardless of
the value of
[`fill-column`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/fill-column).

**Q.** How can I get `fill-paragraph` to always respect the configured
  [`fill-column`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Var/fill-column)
  inside `emacs-lisp-mode`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column` to `nil`.  From the docstring (emphasis mine):

> Value of `fill-column` to use when filling a docstring.
>   **Any non-integer value means do not use a different value of
>   `fill-column' when filling docstrings.**

Please don't do this, though.  There is a reason for this setting:  Emacs shows  docstrings *exactly* like the appear in your code.  If you fill your docstrings at 80 characters, you force your readers to *read* them filled at 80 characters.  Even those readers, who view docstrings on their 11 inch laptops in horizontally split buffers. And they have **no** chance to change the filling in any way.

Comment: Actually, I want to *reduce* the width so that they fit in my blog's code blocks. It's not for actual development.

Comment: @Malabarba Well, that's a valid reason, of course, but I'll leave the warning in my answer, for other readers.

Answer (score 3):

In emacs-lisp-mode the `fill-paragraph-function` is set to `lisp-fill-paragraph`. There is a separate fill column used specifically for docstrings, see`emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column`.

From the variable documentation, you can set `emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column` to any non-integer value to make it use the current `fill-column` instead.